# Is there an error in Casella and Berger's Statistical Inference Example 7.3.21?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

I have been reviewing this great book and I think I found an error not listed in the errata. In example 7.3.21, the authors finish off with the argument that $X-\frac{1}{2}$ is not the best unbiased estimator for $\theta$ for an uniform$(\theta,\theta+1)$ distribution. In fact even $X-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{sin(2\pi X)}{2\pi}$ is better since its is unbiased AND has variance .071. But I think that this last estimator has variance $\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{8\pi^2}-\frac{cos(2\pi\theta)}{2\pi^2}$ and hence the new estimator is better only when $\frac{1}{8\pi^2}-\frac{cos(2\pi\theta)}{2\pi^2}<0$

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked.

Comment: Can you state details from the example? Not everyone may have the book.

Comment: So you are saying the new estimator is better than the natural estimator for *some* values of $\theta$.  So too is the book.

Comment: I am not questioning the main conclusion of the example which is that $X-\frac{1}{2}$ is not the best unbiased estimator, but rather a minor statement they used to reinforce the conclusion. The last sentence of the example says that the variance of the new estimator equals .071.

Answer (score 2):

For those who not have the book, a brief summary: let $X \sim \text{uniform}(\theta, \theta + 1)$. Then its expected value is $\theta + \dfrac{1}{2}$ and thus one unbiased estimator of $\theta$ is $X - \dfrac{1}{2}$, which has variance $\dfrac{1}{12}$. In particular, for this distribution, unbiased estimators of zero are periodic functions $h$ with period $1$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and using the fact that we desire that
$$\int_{\theta}^{\theta + 1}h(x)\text{ d}x = 0 \text{ for all }\theta\text{.}$$
One such function is $h(x) = \sin(2\pi x)$.

The authors demonstrate that $\text{Cov}\left(X - \dfrac{1}{2}, h(X)\right) = -\dfrac{\cos(2\pi\theta)}{2\pi}$, and because $X - \dfrac{1}{2}$ is correlated with an unbiased estimator of $0$, it cannot be a best unbiased estimator of $\theta$.

Now, let's consider
$$Y = X - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sin(2\pi X)}{2\pi}\text{.}$$
From the prior discussion, $Y$ is obviously unbiased. For the variance, we have that
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(Y) &= \text{Var}\left(X - \dfrac{1}{2} + \dfrac{\sin(2\pi X)}{2\pi} \right) \\
&= \text{Var}\left(X + \dfrac{\sin(2\pi X)}{2\pi}\right) \\
&= \text{Var}(X) + \dfrac{1}{4\pi^2}\text{Var}\left(\sin(2\pi X) \right) + 2\cdot \text{Cov}\left(X, \dfrac{\sin(2\pi X)}{2\pi}\right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{12} + \dfrac{1}{4\pi^2}\text{Var}\left(\sin(2\pi X) \right) + \dfrac{2}{2\pi}\cdot \text{Cov}(X, h(X)) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{12} + \dfrac{1}{4\pi^2}\text{Var}\left(\sin(2\pi X) \right) + \dfrac{1}{\pi} \cdot \left[-\dfrac{\cos(2\pi \theta)}{2\pi}\right] \\
&= \dfrac{1}{12} + \dfrac{1}{4\pi^2}\text{Var}(\sin(2\pi X)) - \dfrac{1}{2\pi^2}\cos(2\pi\theta)\text{.}
\end{align}
Now using the fact that $\sin^2(2\pi X)$ is an unbiased estimator of $0$,
$$\text{Var}(\sin(2\pi X)) = \mathbb{E}\left[\sin^2(2\pi X) \right] = \int_{\theta}^{\theta + 1}\sin^2(2\pi x)\text{ d}x = \dfrac{1}{2}$$
hence we have
$$\text{Var}(Y) = \dfrac{1}{12} + \dfrac{1}{8\pi^2} - \dfrac{1}{2\pi^2}\cos(2\pi\theta)\text{.}$$
There is a bit of nuance that must be pointed out from the textbook:

> it is straightforward to check that the estimator $X - \dfrac{1}{2} + \sin(2\pi X)/(2\pi)$ is unbiased for $\theta$ and has variance less than $\dfrac{1}{12}$ for some $\theta$ values.

The authors *do not* claim that $Y$ is a best unbiased estimator for $\theta$. Rather, we can see that via [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%281%2F12%29%2B%281%2F%288*pi%5E2%29%29+-+cos%282*pi*theta%29%2F%282*pi%5E2%29+%3C+1%2F12+for+theta):

[image]

which, as pointed out in the original question, only occurs for certain values of $\theta$, and not over all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

However, what this *does* show is that $X - \dfrac{1}{2}$ **cannot** be a best unbiased estimator of $\theta$, because it must have the uniformly smallest variance out of all unbiased estimators of $\theta$.

Thus, there is no typo to correct in the book.

Comment: Thank you for filling it the details to the problem. I think there is an error in your computation of Var(Y) where in the second line there should be a plus sign instead of the minus sign. I agree that the main conclusion of the example, namely that $X-\frac{1}{2}$ is not the best unbiased estimator, is unchallenged. What I was asking about in a way is a minor part of the argument where the authors state that Var(Y)=.071. I think that part was the error.

Comment: @UniformIntegrability My edition of Casella and Berger does not make the 0.071 variance claim (I have the 2002 edition, think it's the 7th printing?)

Comment: @UniformIntegrability And thanks, I made the correction to the variance computation

Comment: Ok, I think then the error only occurs in the 7th printing (the one I have). The exact last sentence in my version is: "In fact it is straightforward to check that the estimator $X-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{sin(2\pi X)}{2\pi}$ is unbiased for $\theta$ and has variance $.071<\frac{1}{12}$"